# how to count excel rows with the same values in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file containing 3 columns(source,destination and time) and 140400 rows, I want to count rows with the same soure, destination and time value) similar values in all columns, by this I mean to count the rows containing packet information from the same sources to the same destination and at the same time.(row1:0,1,3 and row102:0,1,3 so we have 2 same rows here), all the values are integer. I tried to use df.iloc but just returns zero, tried to use dictionary but couldnt make it. I would appreciate if someone help me to find a solution.
for t in timestamps:
this is one way I tried but didn't work.

```
for x in range(120):        
    for y in range(120):
        while i < 140400 and df.iloc[i,0] <= t:
        #if df.iloc[i,0]<= t :
            if df.iloc[i, 0] == t and df.iloc[i, 1]==y and df.iloc[i, 2]==x:
                TotalArp[x][y]+=1
            i=i+1
```

[this is the file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcMJx.png)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just want to count rows that all have the same value, right? This should work, despite not being the most efficient way probably:

```
counter = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] == row[1] == row[2]:
        counter += 1
```

Edit:

OK, since I'm too stupid to comment, I'll just edit it here:

```
duplicate_count_df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size().drop_duplicates(subset=list(df.columns)
```

This should lead you into the right direction.

Comment: thanks, but there are different values and I want to have the count for each separately, for example all the rows with col1=1 and col2=2 and col3=5 and the number of col1=2 and col2= 3 and col3=120 how can I separate this values?

Comment: @h.bahar

Ah, I understand. OK, this might help you:

`df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size()`

Comment: it shows the error:---> 10 duplicate_count_df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size().drop_duplicates(subset = ['time' , 'src'  ,'des'])

TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset' I tested the type(df) and its ok  and I tested your version with list but the same error. any other idea for the error?

Comment: Could you show me the line where you create the Dataframe df? Is it a Pandas Dataframe with something like `df = pd.read_csv('stuff.csv')`

Comment: for some resons there were some errors and when I changed the type to numeric they were gone:df = pd.read_excel (r'dataset1.xlsx', columns=['time', 'src', 'des'])
df["time"] = pd.to_numeric(df["time"])
df["src"] = pd.to_numeric(df["src"])
df["des"] = pd.to_numeric(df["des"])

Comment: So it works now with the solution i suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have These Columns in Your DataFrame:
`["Col1" , "Col2" , "Col3" , "Col4"]`
Now you want to count rows that contains equal values in each column of your DataFrame:

```
len(df[df['Col1'] == df['Col2'] == df['Col3'] == df['Col4'])
```

Just easy Like That.

**Update**:
if you would like to get the count by each element specifically :

```
# Create Dictionary to specify count for each element
Properties = {k:0 for k in set([item for elem in df.columns for item in df[elem]])}

# Then Start counting values that are equal in each row
for item in range(len(df)) :
    if df.iloc[item , 0] == df.iloc[item , 1] == df.iloc[item , 2] == df.iloc[item , 3]:
        Properties[df.iloc[item , 0]] += 1

print(Properties)
```

---

Let's See an Example:

```
# Here i have a DataFrame with 2 columns and 3 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3] , '2':[1,1,'-']})
df
```

OutPut :
[image: My Data Frame]

And Then :

```
Properties = {k:0 for k in set([item for elem in df.columns for item in df[elem]])}

for item in range(len(df)) :
    if df.iloc[item , 0] == df.iloc[item , 1]:
        Properties[df.iloc[item , 0]] += 1

Properties
```

Output:

> {1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, '-': 0}

**to better understand**:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but as there are different values, I want to have the count for each separately, for example all the rows with col1=1 and col2=2 and col3=5 and the number of col1=2 and col2= 3 and col3=120 how can I separate this values?

Comment: it returns some of the rows and all have the value zero, just like what I had before.

Comment: @h.bahar so there isn't any kind of rows that you're looking for in your `DataFrame`! Just try costume dataframe and then you know that works.

Comment: @h.bahar Check The Example above.

Comment: thanks shayan, this dataset contains some packet' information time, source and destination. I want to find how many packets have been sent from the same source to the same destination at the same time, so I need to count the rows having the same values in all columns as I said before row1: time:0, src:1, des:2 and row 10 the same values so I have 2 same rows. i hope I could explain better this time.

Comment: @h.bahar please update your question with exact and simple example (as much as your example will be explicit, people better can help you) so I'll try my best, otherwise i can't help much.

Comment: I updated the question and added some more explanatons.

Comment: @h.bahar it's not clear yet. make simple example to show what you exactly expect.